# How to use sortBy with a template

Tags: sorting, kotlin

For instance, I have a BigClass which contains a String (alias) object so I can get it using bigClass.alias
and I have a String array keeps ones in the desired order
For example

```
    val theList: MutableList<BigClass> = listOf(
BigClass(SomeObject("good",anotherObject,context, etc)
BigClass(SomeObject("bad",anotherObject,context2, etc2)
BigClass(SomeObject("okay",anotherObject3,context3, etc3)
)
```

and String array:

```
val strList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("bad", "okay", "good")
```

How to sort **theList** according to **strList** string order?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a efficient way to sort by the ordered list

```
val strList = listOf("bad", "okay", "good")

val order = strList.withIndex().associate { it.value to it.index }
val sorted = theList.sortedBy { order[it.someObject.alias] }
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks